# Хранение фрагментов в активити

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

В активити с BottomNavigation всего 3 путкта меню и 3 фрагмента которые переключаются при навигации. Для одного из них нужно всегда хранить состояние. Рационально ли хранить все 3 фрагмента в памяти как поля активити или лучшей практикой будет при смене фрагментов каждый раз создавать новый объект?

Comment: Как вариант можете использовать `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, у `ViewPager` выставить offscreenlimit 2, чтобы они показывались одновременно, ну и отключить анимацию свайпа, если она вам не нужна, в этом случае не будет необходимости хранить ссылки на `Fragment`-ы

Comment: я в своем проекте вообще для каждого фрагмента сделал отдельный контейнер и у меня все 3 фрагмента остаются живы, включая их вьюхи. тем самым я добился очень быстрого перехода между вкладками, но памяти приложение начало больше потреблять

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае правильной практикой будет не пересоздавать Object фрагмента, без нужной необходимости, даже если у вас 5 табов. 
На практике фрагменты могут быть очень тяжелыми, тогда необходимостью будет являться - освобождение памяти. Но эту ситуацию вы должны учитывать всегда, из-за особенностей Системы, или просто перехода на другой Activity().

Как пример от Google:

```
  AddEditTaskFragment addEditTaskFragment = (AddEditTaskFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.contentFrame);

    if (addEditTaskFragment == null) {
        addEditTaskFragment = mFragment;
   ActivityUtils.addFragmentToActivity(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                addEditTaskFragment, R.id.contentFrame);
    }
```

кончено же его можно написать интересней, например так:

```
 if (fragmentUtils.hasFragment(tag)) fragmentUtils.showFragment(tag);
 else fragmentUtils.addFragment(R.id.frame_fragment_container, lazyFragment.get(), tag);
```